# My Ubuntu 20.04 auto install is failing - how can I open a shell?

Tags: pxe, curtin, subiquity

I have an autoinstall on a custom 20.04 ISO I'm building using Cubic. Subiquity is the Curtin log below and providing a path but I can't  work out how to break into a shell. This happened after `cloud-init` ran.

[image: Curtin log]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hit the key combo `Alt-F2` and get a shell.  This works with both the *legacy* and *live* installers.  Subiquity logs will be in `/var/log/installer`.  The key combo `Alt-F1` will take you back to the installer UI

It looks like you hit the point where subiquity generates a config for curtin.  Either subiquity is failing to generate the config or curtin is failing with the provided config

Answer (score 0):

When using Subiquity Live Server installer (NOT the Desktop installer):

- Look in the top orange bar for the [Help] menu. "Enter a shell" is an option there.
- Or use CTRL+Z or F2

When finished with the shell, the command `exit` will return you to the Subiquity installer.

There's only one tty: You cannot run Subiquity and a shell on different ttys.

Comment: Neither CTRL + Z or F2 seemed to work. This is not the installer rather the subiquity service