# Can't run autoinstall with ubuntu server 20.04

Tags: server, 20.04, system-installation, ftp, cloud-init

Good morning,

I have a problem with starting up autoinstall while booting Ubuntu Server 20.04 ISO.
I have already read all documentation and couple internet manuals but I'm not able to make Ubuntu using user-data file.

I have user-data file prepared by Ubuntu installer. I'm trying to boot it with parameters like:

```
autoinstall ds=nocloud-net;s=ftp://repo/files/ubuntu2004/
```

I created an empty meta-data file, tried a lot of ftp/http, syntax combination for this. Nothing was successful so far. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Each time cloud-init is loading but then it starts interactive installation. I'm running out of ideas :(

Answer (score 2):

FYI, `ftp` is **not** supported by `cloud-init`.  This can be confusing because the documentation used to claim that is was, but that [should be fixed now](https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-init/+bug/1875470).

Since you claim that you also tried `http` without success, here are a few thoughts (for these items I simply replaced `ftp` in your URL with `http` for demonstration purposes)

- wrap the `ds` argument in quotes.  Otherwise `grub` will ignore everything past the `;`.  E.g. `ds="nocloud-net;s=http://repo/files/ubuntu2004/"`.
- confirm the `user-data` file can be downloaded by using `curl` in a terminal.  E.g. this should print your file `curl http://repo/files/ubuntu2004/user-data`.
- check your web server logs to see if the `user-data` and `meta-data` files are being requested by the installer.
- [access a terminal in the installer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1255400/my-ubuntu-20-04-auto-install-is-failing-how-can-i-open-a-shell/1257186#1257186) and check the logs in `/var/log/installer`

Comment: First thank you for support. I tried with http and in the logs I can see error 
/vendor-data file. Do I need to add more files? 

 [10/Sep/2021:06:49:34 +0000] "GET /meta-data HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "Cloud-Init/21.1-19-gbad84ad4-0ubuntu2" "-"
10.206.190.126 - - [10/Sep/2021:06:49:34 +0000] "GET /user-data HTTP/1.1" 200 6712 "-" "Cloud-Init/21.1-19-gbad84ad4-0ubuntu2" "-"
2021/09/10 06:49:34 [error] 33#33: *6 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/vendor-data" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.206.190.126, server: localhost, request: "GET /vendor-data HTTP/1.1", host: "10.206.190.11"

Comment: You don't need a `vendor-data` file.  It sounds like the `user-data` file is downloaded from the web server, so I would check the logs in the installer.